# Strange Amazon EC2 issue with AKIs. Please help me understand

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, kernel

I am booting up some Amazon EC2 instances. Specifically, Alestic instances in us-east for Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04. When I log into those machines I can use "`uname -a`" to check the kernel versions. And as expected, they are different: 2.6.32, 2.6.35 and 2.6.38.

To my great surprise, however, their AKI is actually the same! That is shown in the web-based management portal, and also by the `ec2-describe-instances` command.

When I look into the `/boot` directory, I can see the kernel image files, such as `vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-virtual`. The names are appropriate for what "`uname -a`" shows on that instance and they are also of different sizes.

So, what is going on here? I was under the impression that you can use specific AKIs to get different kernels in your machines. Here I see different kernels, but the same AKI?

If you could help me to understand this, I would much appreciate it.

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

If this is using the pvgrub method ("User Provided Kernel"), the base aki is the same because it's chain loading into a user-defined (by Altesic) kernel.  This is how kernels may now be (carefully) upgraded without breaking your box in previous AMIs.

> Check that the AKI matches one listed in the PDF below.

References:

"Enabling User Provided Kernels in Amazon EC2"

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3967